# Adding ?skipmobile tag to all links if ?skipmobile in url

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, onclick, setattribute

I have a website ([www.team2342.org](http://www.team2342.org)) that auto redirects to a mobile site ([m.team2342.org](http://m.team2342.org)) using javascript. I want to give the option for users to see the full website on mobile. I have done this through overriding the redirect by adding `?skipmobile` to the end of the url. The problem is whenever they tap a link to go to another page, the `?skipmobile` gets removed and they get redirected to the mobile site. I've written code to add `?skipmobile` to the end of the `href` link using the `onclick` attribute; I just can't get it to apply the onclick attribute to all links! Here is what I have... Thanks for your help!

`if (document.location.search.indexOf("skipmobile") >= 0) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("a").createAttribute("onclick","a = this; url = a.getAttributeNode('href').value; var smurl = url + '?skipmobile'; a.setAttribute('href', smurl);")
    }
    else if (screen.width < 699)
    {
        document.location = "http://m.team2342.org";
    }`

Note: The code above is in the `<head>` in a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a prefix, instead of a query parameter and ensure that all the links are relative. That way the user stays within the prefix site.
E.g. www.site.com/ redirects to mobile and www.site.com/no-mobile/... forwards to /... (?skipMobile).